# How to add offline 3D city white model in mapbox

Tags: 3d, mapbox

I want to add offline 3D city white model in mapbox using mapbox-gl.js.Like this: 
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/3d-buildings
[demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1h31.png)
What's kind of these data formats? (.shp?.obj?...)
Could I use Three.js to load these model data?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolutely you can! Have a look at https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-3d-model/.

It loads a glTF model, but you can load in anything that is supported by THREE.js including `obj` files.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to check out the latest version of [threebox](https://github.com/jscastro76/threebox)
as it enables you to do things like these below with a few lines of code

```
<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoianNjYXN0cm8iLCJhIjoiY2s2YzB6Z25kMDVhejNrbXNpcmtjNGtpbiJ9.28ynPf1Y5Q8EyB_moOHylw';

var origin = [2.294514, 48.857475];

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9',
    center: origin,
    zoom: 18,
    pitch: 60,
    bearing: 0
});

map.on('style.load', function () {

    map
        .addLayer({
            id: 'custom_layer',
            type: 'custom',
            renderingMode: '3d',
            onAdd: function (map, mbxContext) {

                window.tb = new Threebox(
                    map,
                    mbxContext,
                    {
                        defaultLights: true,
                    }
                );

                // import tower from an external glb file, downscaling it to real size
                // IMPORTANT: .glb is not a standard MIME TYPE, you'll have to add it to your web server config,
                // otherwise you'll receive a 404 error
                var options = {
                    obj: '/3D/eiffel/eiffel.glb',
                    type: 'gltf',
                    scale: 0.01029,
                    units: 'meters',
                    rotation: { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }, //default rotation
                    adjustment: { x: -0.5, y: -0.5, z: 0 } // place the center in one corner for perfect positioning and rotation
                }

                tb.loadObj(options, function (model) {

                    model.setCoords(origin); //position
                    model.setRotation({ x: 0, y: 0, z: 45.7 }); //rotate it

                    tb.add(model);
                })

            },

            render: function (gl, matrix) {
                tb.update();
            }
        });
})

</script>
```

**- 3D models built-in and custom animations**

[image: 3D models built-in and custom animations]

**- Full raycast support MouseOver/Mouseout, Selected, Drag&Drop, Drag&Rotate, Wireframe**

[image: MouseOver/Mouseout, Selected, Drag&Drop, Drag&Rotate, Wireframe]

**- CSS2D Tooltips and Labels that consider altitude**

[image: CSS2D Tooltips and Labels that consider altitude]

**- Three.js and Mapbox cameras sync with depth adjustment **

[image: Three.js and Mapbox cameras sync with depth adjustment]

**- Include geolocated models of monuments**

[image: Eiffel tower gif]